# Providing references through a file

Tags: labels

Does anyone know how to provide references through a file rather than by compiling labels? Specifically, I want to compile only a specific part of a LaTeX file into a PDF, but I want to make sure that the reference numbers and section numbers are consistent with the PDF of the entire file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is to use LaTeX's `\include` mechanism. It allows you to specify only specific parts of the document to be compiled while keeping references/pagination/etc. the same as for the whole document. `\include` works like `input` except that you don't provide the `.tex` extension and every `\include` implicitly starts a new page. E.g.,

```
\documentclass{book}
\includeonly{chapter1,chapter2} % leave out \includeonly to compile whole document
\begin{document}
\include{frontmatter}
\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\include{chapter3}
\include{appendices}
\include{backmatter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\includeonly` was what I was looking for thanks.